# Javascript Function With JQuery POST Always Returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, post

I have no idea what's going on here and was hoping someone could help, I'm sure it's something easy going on that I'm just missing.

I have a function in javascript that has a JQuery post inside of it.  I would like to return the results of the post which is just text and put it in a variable.  The number is coming back correctly from the Post but when I put it in the variable, the variable says "undefined".  Any ideas?

```
var total = GetTotalSize();
alert(total);

function GetTotalSize(){
    var i = "";
    $.post("Handlers/GetTotal.ashx", {id : $("#hID").val()}, function(data){
        i = data.toString();
        return i;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it like that.  Remember, the "A" in AJAX means "Asynchronous".  The callback function you provide to `$.post()` will execute well after `GetTotalSize()` executes and returns.

You'll need to restructure your code to accommodate this.  I can't be specific in my recommendation because I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but here's a possibility.

```
$.post("Handlers/GetTotal.ashx", {id : $("#hID").val()}, function(data)
{
  doSomethingWithTotalSize( data.toString() );
});

function doSomethingWithTotalSize( totalSize )
{
  // whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Peter is absolutely right, but you can force the $.ajax method to work synchronously by passing `async: false`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are returning `i` outside of the callback function.  Basically when you return `i`, its contents don't exist yet, and won't exist until the server returns the data to your callback function.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response!  I tried your suggestion and updated my example code but I am still having the same problem, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function GetTotalSize(callback) {    
  $.post("Handlers/GetTotal.ashx", {id : $("#hID").val()}, function(outputData) {
       callback(outputData);
    });
}

function DoSomething(data)
{
   //....
}

GetTotalSize(DoSomething);
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older post, but a solution for me was to use `complete:[delegate]` rather than `success`.  This ensures that the `callback` is complete.