# return object from function is undefined from $.post in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a jquery post function that returns a data object from a php code block.

```
$.post("get_chat_history.php", {
    item_id : item_id,
    participant_1 : participant_1,
    participant_2 : participant_2
}, function(data) {
    alert(data);

    return data;

});
```

this is called from the following function in another javascript file

```
var data = getChatHistory(current_member_id,item_global["user"]    ["member_id"],item_global["id"]);
alert(data);
```

now inside the $.post the alert(data) throws out the correct values in json format, but when I test the same value returned to the calling function I get undefined.

Is there something I'm missing as I want to keep this function generic and callable from elsewhere??

Regards,

Sapatos

Comment: Ajax is **asynchronous** (the **A** means asynchronous). Why do you think you have to provide a callback? If you could simply *return* a value, then `$.post` could return that value directly and you would not need a callback.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Function With JQuery POST Always Returns undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400854/javascript-function-with-jquery-post-always-returns-undefined)

Comment: Check out the related questions.  There are several similar questions which should prove helpful.

Answer (score 1):

That's because this function runs asyncronim and returns data to anonymous function `function(data) {}`. Use callbacks.

Here is example:

```
function getFoo(callback){
    $.get('somepage.html', function(data){
        callback(data)
    })
}
getFoo(function (data){
     // do something with data
})​
```

Comment: Or shorter: `$.get('somepage.html', callback)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that jQuery.post is asynchronous. When getChatHistory is being called it has not yet received a reply from the server so it is `undefined`.

For this to work I would implement `getChatHistory` as a function that takes the data you need to pass to the server, and a function to perform when the 'success' part is triggered.

[For more on callbacks](http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/).